# (Solved) When adding a new contact, redirected to Civicrm home page

Tags: contacts

This started after upgrading Civicrm. When I click on any Civicrm menu item, I get redirected to the Civicrm home page. Please advice.

This is the url shown in the browser: /civicrm/contact/add_reset_1_ct_Individual

Comment: Can you clear civicrm cache?

Comment: to clear your menu cache try going to civicrm/menu/rebuild

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Clearing the cache for CiviCRM or the menu cache doesn't resolve the problem for me.

Comment: The database record in the navigation table has civicrm/contact/add?reset=1&ct=Individual.

But this is the url shown in the browser: /civicrm/contact/add_reset_1_ct_Individual

Is there somewhere else that this URL could be stored?

Answer (score 3):

Solved. I used a copy of the navigation menu table for first CiviCRM installation and reset the table. Cleared the CiviCRM caches and my browser cache and the admin menu is working properly.